# Bad photo quality captured from camera or gallery

Tags: android, image, base64, compression

I have a problem in my app:

i must get photo from camera or gallery, show it in a small imageView and sent it to server in base64 format (i don't need save image as file in the phone).

i can take photo but with very bad quality! 
The solutions found in internet don't work for me
Can you help me?

here is the code

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                bitmap_photo = (Bitmap) imageReturnedIntent.getExtras().get("data");
                Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap_photo,
                        70, 70, true);
                userImage.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
                bitmap_photo = newBitmap;
            }

            break;
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                userImage.setImageURI(selectedImage);

                try {
                    bitmap_photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),selectedImage);
                    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap_photo,
                            70, 70, true);
                    bitmap_photo = newBitmap;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

and this is the code to convert image to base64:

```
public String getBase64Image(){
    if(bitmap_photo!=null){
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap_photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
        String base64image = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return base64image;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

thank you!

Comment: Why you set the size just 70 * 70?

Comment: because the server does not accept too large base64 (if the string is too long i get an error)

Comment: So, do you expect an icon to have a quality comparable to that of a Full HD picture?

Comment: not the same quality, but I wish you could not see the pixels.. the image is no longer defined

Comment: It is not possible to convert the big size image to small without losing the quality. Like my device capture the photo with resolution of 4128 * 2322 and now I am going to convert that image 70 * 70 then what would be the expectation from image?

Comment: ok, but if i don't resize the image before convert it to base64, i have a too long base64 string. is there a solution to this? Because the problem is that i can't send base64 image to server

Comment: Pictorial images (bitmaps) are different from vectorial ones (SVGs, VectorDrawables, ...). When scaled, they average the surrounding pixel color and try to mantain a certain color coherence. But they generate a pixellated result.

Comment: Instead of **resizing** your image, you may consider **cropping** a meaningful detail to fit the desired size window.

Comment: can you explain me how to cropping the image?

Comment: Too broad. Google for a tutorial - you'll find a godzillion ones.